# Changing similar appended elements separately

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on something that creates a form based on choices you give it (text/textfield/dropdown). When I create 2 dropdowns at once I am not sure how to write in a way that the computer can tell the 2 elements aren't the same, specifically when adding new inputs in my dropdown creator it can't tell multiple dropdowns apart.

Here's the Javascript function I'm using for it

```
$('#submit').on('click', function() {
    $("select").each(function() {
        switch($(this).val()) {
            case "text":
                $("#form").append('<p><input type="text"/> <button class="remInput">Remove</button></p>');
                break;
            case "note":
                $("#form").append('<p><textarea></textarea> <button class="remInput">Remove</button></p> ');
                break;
            case "dd":
                $("#form").append('<p><select id="ddFinal"><option></option></select> <button class="remInput">Remove</button></p>');
                $("#ddCreator").append('<button id="ddAddInput">Add Another Field</button> <p class="ddP"><input type="text" name="ddText"/></p> <button id="ddSubmit">Submit</button>');

                break;
        }       
    });
    $('#inputDiv').empty();
    $('#ddAddInput').on('click', function() {
        $("p[class*='ddP']").append('<input type="text" name="ddText"/>');     
    });
    $('#ddSubmit').on('click', function() {
        $("input[name*='ddText']").each(function() {
                $('#ddFinal').append('<option>'+$(this).val()+'</option>');
        });
        $('#ddCreator').empty();
        $('#ddFinal').removeAttr('id');
    });
});
```

The problem is with the ddAddInput function because it doesn't specify between multiple p class="ddp" elements but I'm not really sure what I should be putting instead. Hope this question makes sense.

Here's the fiddle I'm currently working on http://jsfiddle.net/me74Z/15/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several flaws in approach that need to be remedied.

First:  -  element Id's are unique in a page by definition. Use classes instead.

Next, your event handlers are being added from within another event handler. If you were to change all the ID's you have to classes and the corresponding selectors in the event handlers, you would end up compounding events.

What compounding events means is if you add the same handler twice to an element, it will fire twice.

Using event delegation would be easier. Set up your event delegation outside of the current click handler for `#submit`

```
   $(document).on('click', '.ddSubmit', function() {....});
```

Now, as for how to handle instances, within every event handler `this` is the element that is the target of the event.
Using `$(this)` and jQuery traverse methods you can work with the target's parent and siblings or whatever you need to do.

I would suggest you wrap each level in a container to simplify the traversals. I'll call container class `row` so that a generic traverse from an event target can look something like:

```
var someField=  $(this).closest('.row').find('.someField');
```

WHen remove button is clicked, simply remove the parent row